# AlternationCount not found in listview xaml + application métro

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Why i can't found the memeber  AlternationCount in a listview XAML in my Windows8 application??

Best regards

Comment: it's not part of [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) as it is for WPF/Silverlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you could use the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) property and chain its `ContainerFromItem` and `IndexFromContainer` methods to get the index of your item and then use a converter to get a background color from the index.

```
public class Item : BindableBase
{
    public ItemsControl itemsControl {get;set;}

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get{
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Index
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(
                itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this)
            );
        }
    }
}

public sealed partial class ItemContainerGeneratorTest : App1.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{
...
    public ObservableCollection<Item> test 
    {
        get
        {
            var test = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            test.Add(new Item() { Name = "Index for item 1: ", itemsControl = ItemsControlControl });
            test.Add(new Item() { Name = "Index for item 2: ", itemsControl = ItemsControlControl });
            test.Add(new Item() { Name = "Index for item 3: ", itemsControl = ItemsControlControl });
            test.Add(new Item() { Name = "Index for item 4: ", itemsControl = ItemsControlControl });
            test.Add(new Item() { Name = "Index for item 5: ", itemsControl = ItemsControlControl });
            test.Add(new Item() { Name = "Index for item 6: ", itemsControl = ItemsControlControl });
            return test;
        }
    }
...
}

<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=test}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that this example *doesn't* currently handle changes to the collection (i.e. `OnPropertyChanged` isn't called for `Index` when the collection changes).

Comment: An example would be helpful here.

Comment: @cederlof There ya go

Comment: On further reflection, putting the Index lookup in an `IValueConverter` would probably make more sense.